# Is the powerset of a regular set also a regular set?

Tags: regular-languages, sets

If so, where can I find a proof of it? If not, is there a counterexample?

By powerset of a regular language I mean the set of all subsets of a regular language.

Thank you, Marcus.

Comment: If $L$ is a regular language (i.e., a set of words), what does it mean for $2^L$ (i.e., a set of sets) to be regular? Are you asking if every language in $2^L$ is regular?

Comment: No. I am asking if 2^L itself is a regular set. That is, if it can be described by a right linear grammar, a regular expression or a finite automaton.

Comment: Can you provide a definition or a reference to a definition of "regular set"? Is it a language? If so what is the alphabet this language is defined on?

Comment: A regular set - or a regular language - L is a set that can by described by means of a right linear grammar or a regular expression or a finite automaton. The alphabet doesn´t matter really. The point is: if L is regular, is 2^L also regular, whatever L?

Comment: A language is a subset of $\Sigma^*$ where $\Sigma$ is an alphabet. The alphabet is important... if $L$ is a regular language on the alphabet $\Sigma$ then $2^L \not\subseteq \Sigma^*$ is not a even a language on $\Sigma$...

Comment: Sure, the alphabet of 2^L must be different from the alphabet of L. Still, is 2^L a regular language? If L is finite (and consequently regular), then 2^L is also finite (and regular). But what if L is regular and infinite?

Comment: As @Yuval Filmus points out in a comment, if $L$ is infinite then $2^L$ is not countable. Every language is countable so $2^L$ is not even a language.

Comment: Right. Indeed, I just noticed that L \in 2^L and, since L is infinite, it can not be represented as a finite string in 2^L. Thus, 2^L is not a language and I can not ask whether it is regular or not. My question is not proper, unless L is finite and (only) in this case the answer is yes. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  In computer science, a *language* is normally defined to be a subset of $\{0,1\}^*$.  If $L$ is a language, then the powerset $2^L$ is not a subset of $\{0,1\}^*$, so it is not a language.

(See e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language#Definition.)

If $L$ is finite, then the powerset $2^L$ is finite, so [as Emil Jeřábek points out](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/123918/is-the-powerset-of-a-regular-set-also-a-regular-set/123919?noredirect=1#comment259677_123919), there is a way you can encode it so its encoding is a regular language, since all finite languages are regular.

If $L$ is infinite, then [as Yuval Filmus points out](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/123918/is-the-powerset-of-a-regular-set-also-a-regular-set/123919?noredirect=1#comment259509_123919), the powerset $2^L$ is not countable, so there is no way to encode it as a language.  Thus, when $L$ is an infinite regular language, then the answer to your question is "no, not even if you're allowed to choose a reasonable encoding".

Comment: Even worse, if $L$ is infinite then $2^L$ is not even countable, so there is no reasonable encoding.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, oh, good point, I missed that!  Thanks.

Comment: If $L$ is finite, then $2^L$ is regular no matter what encoding you use, because all finite languages are regular.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek, oh, right!  Thank you.